# How to reuse variable of A fun to the variable of B class?

Tags: python, class, scope

```
class Fun:
    def __init__(self):
        self.converted_list = self.convert_list()
        self.map_result = self.map_list()
        #avilable for other funs
        
    def convert_list(self):
        return list(user_input)
        
    def map_list(self):      
        global fun_name 
        return list(map(lambda x: getattr(x, fun_name)(), self.converted_list))
        #clarify: map x.fun_name() -> converted_list
        
    def return_bool(self):
        for each_bool in self.map_result: #map_result(type) -> list
            if each_bool:
                return True
            else:
                pass
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_input = input()
    fun=Fun()
    if 0 < len(user_input) < 1000:
        fun_set = ['isalnum','isalpha','isdigit','islower','isupper']
        for fun_name in fun_set: #bool_result(5) in fun_set elements
            print(fun.return_bool())
```

Question: how to use fun_name in for loop to fun_name of map_list of class Fun?
I found nonlocal, global.But I don't know detail.I also tried to code self.fun_name

Comment: You're not actually using `fun_name` list elements?

Comment: yes,I want to use fun_name in list to function.In fact,I am solving the problem https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/string-validators/problem?isFullScreen=true

Comment: The problem is that you are relying on your global variable, but that is only seen by your instance of `Fun` when it is initialized. This is absolutely the wrong way to go about this anyway, the whole point of a class is to avoid mutable global state. The simplest thing you could do is add a `func` parameter to your methods, or make it a mutable attribute on your class, don't rely on mutable global variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you "stringifying" the names of the string methods you want to invoke? Functions are objects, so just make an array of functions/callables:

```
methods = [str.isdigit, str.islower, str.isupper]

for method in methods:
    print(method("hello"))
```

Output:

```
False
True
False
```

This example works because the first parameter of these instance methods will be a reference to the (string) instance itself, in this case the string `"hello"`. In other words, `"hello".islower()` is identical to `str.islower("hello")`, for example.

Comment: thanks, but still the problem remains.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "Solution.py", line 4, in __init__
  File "Solution.py", line 12, in map_list
  File "Solution.py", line 12, in <lambda>
NameError: name 'fun_name' is not defined

Comment: I removed all' ' in fun_set.But I want to use fun_name in for loop at fun_name in map_list

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr // The reason why I stringy elements is that getattr(obj, name) name ->must be string. This link saying

Comment: @Mango-danbi there is no reason to use strings to solve your problem, you should just use this method, which is a lot cleaner

Answer (score 0):

You have massively over-complicated this challenge.

All you need is:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = input()
    for f in str.isalnum, str.isalpha, str.isdecimal, str.islower, str.isupper:
        print(any(f(c) for c in s))
```